# Not viewing properly when open a image through ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I am trying to open a image using ACTION_VIEW with following steps

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION, true);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/storage/emulated/0/Media/Images/sent/IMG_149435406522784_1361292.jpg"), "image/*");
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

In some phones above logic is working, but in some phones showing question mark image.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: on which `some phones` does it not work?

Comment: also why you use `"video/*"` mime type for image?

Comment: Do not hardcode path to your `.jpg` file, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` because on different devices it might be different.

Comment: I am using "Image/*". In my code I am using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() only. This issue is coming in Cyanogen OS phones.